# Bootstrap Expand Div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a website that does the same thing this website does. www.treasurelimo.com If you scroll down on the homepage and look at 'popular destination'. When you hoover over the images the blue area expands and more info is seen.

I'm using wordpress but don't want to use any plugins. Right now I have those images being populated from other posts. Here is how mine works. Here is my site: www.sealfitdev.demosite.us/coaching-staff I got the CSS to place the words inside of picture, I just need it to expand when I hoover over it. Can anyone help me or point me to a post that shows how I can do that? I was looking over the bootstrap documentation and I wasn't successful. Thanks

Comment: Your site throws Forbidden Error. Create a plunkr and show us what you have done

Comment: sorry here you go: http://sealfitdev.demosite.us/coaching-staff/

Comment: You need to show what you have done on this site itself. Anyway here is the tutorial: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/slide_image_hover_using_css3.htm

Comment: Thank you that really helps! But with that tutorial its one image where you only show the top part first then unhide the bottom. In my case its text that is being populated from a database field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish the effect using CSS transitions (see some basic [examples here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)).

See an example of this for your use-case [at this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/s12tzy6x/) *(not a particularly clean example, but it should illustrate the concept)*.

I've taken the markup from your site and simplified it a little for clarity.

```
<div class="employee-thumb pull-left">
    <div class="inner">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/people/elon-musk_416x416.jpg" />
        <div class="info">
            <p>Elon Musk</p>
            <p>Additional information including buttons</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in the CSS, we can set `.info` to be absolutely positioned within the relative positioned parent, `.inner`. Since `.inner`'s overflow is hidden the content can be pushed outside our visibility by adjusting the absolute positioning.

```
.inner { 
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    max-width: 150px; 
} 
.inner .info { 
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: -4em; 
}
```

On hovering over `.inner`, `.info`, the absolute positioning of bottom returns to 0, sliding the content up.

```
.inner:hover .info { 
    bottom: 0em; 
}
```

And we animate the whole thing using a CSS transition.

```
.inner .info { 
    transition: all 0.3s ease; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease; 
}
```